# JPA Data Repository result losing its data type

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to get the below code to show my query results.  Unfortunately it's not working.

```
@Transactional
public interface ContentRepository extends JpaRepository<Content,Integer>{

     @Query(nativeQuery=true, value="SELECT content_type, COUNT(*) FROM dbo.content WHERE status_id = :statusId GROUP BY content_type")
     List<Map<String, Integer>> getContentCountByType(@Param("statusId")Short statusId);
```

On my service layer I do...

```
@Service
public class ContentService {
     @Transactional
     public Map<ContentType, Integer> getContentCountByType() {
         List<Map<String, Integer>> rawContentCount = contentRepository.getContentCountByType(Status.DRAFT);
         Map<ContentType, Integer> contentCount = new HashMap<ContentType, Integer>();
         Map<String, Integer> objects = rawContentCount.get(0);
```

`objects` ends up being `Object[]` in the variable debugger.  I'm unsure why it's not obeying the `Map<String, Integer>` that I've told it to use.

I was thinking as an alternative I could just return a list of objects.  I'm trying to Google around trying to figure out what keywords to search for to find such a result.  Though ideally I'd like to avoid having to create an object just for this query result if it would just return `Map`!

Comment: Why do you think that Spring Data can implicitly convert `Object[]` to `Map`? Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: I was able to find http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-querying-executing in section `10.4.1.2`, but I still don't understand why it can't handle `Map<String, Integer>`.  I'm working off of that example trying to get it to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting my query results as `Object[]` and using the documentation here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-querying-executing at section `10.4.1.2` solved my issue